# Kernelshark segmentation fault on capture

Tags: segmentation-fault, kernel, real-time, ubuntu-16.10

I am trying to run kernelshark in a virtual machine, Ubuntu 16.10 with an rt kernel (4.8.15).
If I try to capture without `sudo` I get a popup message saying that there are "`no events or plugins found`".
If I try to capture with `sudo` I get a segmentation fault.
I've tried to run kernelshark and to use the capture function on a non-rt kernel as well, yet the result is the same.
Is there any way to workaround this? Can someone recommend a visualizer similar to kernelshark ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there are some issues with ubuntu 16.10.
After switching over to ubuntu 16.04 everything worked perfectly.